# iPhone (Xcode) interface builder resources

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I am looking for resources (especially video) to show how to use Xcode's interface builder properly for iPhone development. For some reason it just doesn't click how everything fits together and how this should be used properly.

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the example apps and videos on Apple's [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/), Pragmatic Programmers have a [good book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) and some [decent videos](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdiphone/writing-your-first-iphone-application) as well.

Comment: Thanks. The resources were great. Cheers Stephen

Answer (score 2):

Another site is <s>[iPhone Programming Tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/)</s>. It's free, but I am considering buying the videos and book mentioned by Abie.

Edit: Decided to look through my history and found this dead link.